# error selecting child link inside multiple divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, filter, each

I have 4 divs with class `v_block`. Each one has 2 links with class `more`. I'm trying to target the first link only in each div. Here's the code http://jsfiddle.net/AAznD/2/

In real example (it's displayed dynamically), I'm trying to change the background image of the link to make the first one appear with the wide border and the second to show just the word as you can see in the snapshot link below

it targets all the links with class "more" inside the div but it works great on jsfiddle

```
$(".v_block").each(function() {
  $(".v_block a.more:first-child").css({"background-image":"url(images/wide_more.gif)","width":"338px","height":"14px","left":"-23px"});
});
```

Here's a snapshot: http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/8687/capturemrb.jpg.

> [image: http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/8687/capturemrb.jpg].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `this` within the `each`, as `this` will be the specific `div` for that loop iteration; then use `find` to find the `a.more` elements *within* that `div`.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AAznD/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".v_block").each(function() {
        $(this).find("a.more").filter(':first').css({"color":"#d31577","text-decoration":"none"});
    });
});
```

You can also use `first()` instead of `filter(":first")`.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".v_block").each(function() {
        $(this).find("a.more").first().css({"color":"#d31577","text-decoration":"none"});
    });
});
```

Comment: works great thank you so much. i'm still learning i really appreciate your help